# Phantom redirect? I can't find or 'turn off' the redirect

Tags: domains, redirects, shared-hosting

I changed domains and redirected the old domain to the new one and then eventually completely deleted the hosting for that old domain. Recently I've decided I want to use it and I've opened up hosting under that domain again and uploaded some stuff but I can't 'turn off' the redirect. It isn't listed under the hosting of the old domain - I think it might be set in a file somewhere but I wasn't sure where to look. The old domain is theR3journa1.com (notice the 1)

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Where/how exactly did you configure the redirect in the first place? And what do you mean exactly by "completely deleted the hosting"? Did you simply remove the files that make up the website? Or did you close your hosting account with this provider?

Answer (score 1):

Your name server records (NS) point to `ns2.dns-parking.com` and `ns1.dns-parking.com`.   Based on their name, that looks like DNS servers set up by a domain registrar for default tasks such as showing "site coming soon" notices and issuing redirects for alternate domain names.

Looking up `whois` for that domain, those servers are owned by Hostinger.   You must be using them for domain registration.  You need to log into your account there and set your NS records to point to your DNS host.  Your web host should be able to tell you what the values should be, but must likely it will be the same values as for your other domain name.